# How to integrate $ \int_0^\infty \sin x \cdot x ^{-1/3} dx$ (using Gamma function)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

How can I calculate the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty x ^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sin x \, dx$$

WolframAlpha gives me $$ \frac{\pi}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)}$$

How does WolframAlpha get this?

I don't understand how we can rearrange the formula in order to apply the gamma-function here. Any helpful and detailed hint/answer is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts, looking for the integral definition of the gamma function (look on wikipedia) in your answer?

Comment: You can integrate this using Ramanujan Master Theorem$$\int_0^{\infty} x^{s-1} f(x) dx=\Gamma(s) \lambda(-s)$$  where $\lambda(-s)$ is the part of is a term function multiplied inside the series expression for $e^{-x}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a generalization, for $0\lt a\lt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(e^{ia\pi/2}\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x-e^{-ia\pi/2}\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)\Gamma(a)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The changes of variables $x\mapsto ix$ and $x\mapsto-ix$ used in the second equation above, are justified because
$$
\int_{\gamma_k} z^{a-1}e^{-z}\,\mathrm{d}z=0\tag{2}
$$
where $\gamma_1=[0,R]\cup Re^{i\frac\pi2[0,1]}\cup iR[1,0]$ and $\gamma_2=[0,R]\cup Re^{-i\frac\pi2[0,1]}\cup-iR[1,0]$ contain no singularities.

Plugging $a=\frac23$ into $(1)$ and using [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula#known_formula), gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{-1/3}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)\\
&=\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)\frac{\pi\csc\left(\frac\pi3\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use the integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) in conjunction with [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).

Comment: Using Euler's formula we get for the integral: $ \frac{1}{2i}\int\limits_0^\infty  (e^{ix}-e^{-ix}) x ^\frac{-1}{3} dx$. How can we here apply the integral expression of $\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx$ ? What shall we do with the imaginary unit i in $e^{îx}$?

Comment: @M_a_th_ias First you can save yourself some trouble by writing $\text{Im} \left ( \int_0^\infty e^{ix} x^{-1/3} dx \right )$.

Comment: @M_a_th_ias: You are indeed correct in noticing that the upper limit will no longer be the infinity along the positive real semi-axis, but rather a complex one, along a different direction in the bi-dimensional plane. However, the result is still the same. Just evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^k~e^{ax}~dx$ by using a simple substitution, then let $a=i$, and take the imaginary part of the whole expression.