# How to prove this relation $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^b}dx\,=\,\frac{1}{2}\pi\,a^{b-1}\frac{1}{\Gamma(b)\sin(\frac{b\pi}{2})}$?

Tags: calculus

How to prove the following relation if $a>0$
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^b}dx\,=\,\frac{1}{2}\pi\,a^{b-1}\frac{1}{\Gamma(b)\sin(\frac{b\pi}{2})}, \,\,\,\, 0< \operatorname{Re} b <2
$$

Comment: Short answer: by the Laplace transform and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function. I guess this question has been asked many times.

Comment: one can also compute the definite integral in terms of the incomplete gamma function and $1-b$ and $ i ax$ and find the limits at $0$ and $\infty$

Comment: Note that [Robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1226947/272831) and [Lucian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1222849/272831) both cover integrals of the form$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^b}~\mathrm dx$$All that's left is to let $ax\mapsto x$ to get the corresponding integrals.